# How to import mdb to sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I have a vb application. Now I have developed that same vb application in Asp.net. In vb I had used MSAccess database. In asp.net I am using Sql server. Now I want to Move or copy the MSaccess database data into Sql server.

Answer (score 11):

Open your MS Access database, go to tools/database utilities/upsizing wizard. You're done.

Just follow the wizard's steps, make sure you have administrative rights on the SQL server, check all your steps with the integrated help for detailled table/indexes/rules upsizing.

Some database will not upsize easily, due to specific Access/Jet configuration that cannot be imported into SQL. [This company](http://www.ssw.com.au) has a small module to check this kind of issue and might also propose its own upsizing wizard [here](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/UpsizingPRO).

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Access, if I recall has a Sql upsizing wizard, atleast 2k7 does, previous versions might have it also.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use SQL Server directly to import an Access MDB file into a SQL Server database. In SQL Server 2000, this was done using DTS. In SQL Server 2005/2008, this is done with SSIS.

Have a look here for a tutorial:

http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm

Answer (score 4):

If you've got an existing ODBC connection to the MS Access DB, then you can create a sql 2005 database, right click and choose Import (in Management Studio) and run through the import wizard pointing the datasource at the MS Access data connection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In fact, just looked again and there is an option to point directly at an MS Access file. Not tried this though. Happy importing :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Import wizard in the SQL server. Select the source as the MDB and the destination as your SQL server.

Comment: This is the simplest solution. You can import the tables in an existing database.

Answer (score 1):

The upsizing wizard in Access 2007 didn't work for me with SQL Server 2008 Express SP1, but this tool (after an amazingly annoying installation process) worked quite well:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=133b59c2-c89c-4641-bebb-6d04476ec1ba&DisplayLang=en

Comment: link dead; goes to generic MS Download page.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 it's quite hard to match the local version of Access that has the "upsizing wizard" or a similar feature. Also SQL Server Management Studios import/export through SSIS packages sometimes have trouble recognizing column types. I've came across Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access which looks like a stand-alone version of upsizing wizard with a lot of features and verbosity.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255

Comment: you're out here doing the gods' work in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

i think the probs is with data in tables ,not the table. All the tables might have primary keys. so the next run , due to primary key violation  the package is getting failed. before each dump, delete the enteries in the existing sql server  by using  "Execute sql task " in ctrl flow.

if (table exits ) then 
delete * from table

Comment: This answer looks to me like it ought to be a comment. Of course, with only 1 point of reputation, you can't post comments. Which answer was this in reference to?