# Other way to optimize this C# Code?

Tags: c#, optimization, streaming, file-conversion

I creating a conversion of mdb records to sql records, for me it is working fine..
but when the records much larger the speed is very slow.. I think there is other way to optimize the parsing and extracting of the records??

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;    

namespace conMDBToSQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            // string sFileName = "C:\\sqlrecords.mdb";
            string sFileName = "C:\\sample.mdb";
            OleDbConnection _con = new OleDbConnection( @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sFileName + ";Mode=Share Exclusive;User Id=admin;Password=;" );
            try
            {
                _con.Open();

                string sTableName = "users";

                string strSQL = String.Empty;

                strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + sTableName + " ORDER BY 1";
                OleDbCommand _cmd = new OleDbCommand( strSQL, _con );
                _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OleDbDataReader _dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader( CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly );

                ArrayList _Arr = new ArrayList();


                DataTable dt = _dr.GetSchemaTable();
                foreach ( DataRow drow in dt.Rows )
                {
                    // Console.Write( drow[0].ToString() + "\n" );
                    _Arr.Add( drow[0].ToString() );
                }
                _dr.Close();
                _cmd.Dispose();


                strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + sTableName + " ORDER BY 1";
                _cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, _con);
                _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                _dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader();

                string s_fields = String.Empty;
                string s_values = String.Empty;
                int arr_count = _Arr.Count - 1;
                while (_dr.Read()) 
                {
                    for(int i_a = 0; i_a <= arr_count;i_a++)
                    {
                        if (i_a <= arr_count)
                        {
                            s_fields += _Arr[i_a].ToString() + ",";
                            s_values += "'" + _dr[i_a].ToString() + "',";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            s_fields += _Arr[i_a].ToString();
                            s_values += "'" + _dr[i_a].ToString() + "'";
                        }
                    }

                    // Build, query
                    strSQL = String.Empty;
                    strSQL = "INSERT INTO " + sTableName + "("+ s_fields +") VALUES ("+ s_values +")";

                    // Write, text file
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sFileName, true, Encoding.UTF8);
                    sw.Write(strSQL);
                    sw.Close();
                    sw = null;
                }


                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Finished..");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch ( OleDbException olex )
            {
                throw olex;
            }
            finally 
            {
                _con.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: maybe more fitted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Seems like the best way to accomplish this task is really not to write any code at all.  There are tools built into access to import this data into SQL server without a custom code solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370619/how-to-import-mdb-to-sql-server

Comment: Nikhil, what is you scenario? We might be able to suggest even something more powerful and faster if we know what your requirements are.

Comment: use for instead foreach and don't use ToString() (_Arr.Add( drow[0].ToString() );) when using ArrayList, you can put object there. And yes, use StringBuilder it is much more efficiently.

Comment: I don't understand this condition if (i_a <= arr_count)
in the for... you are already using this condition in for. Didn't you want to use != instead? If so, I suggest use i_a < arr_count and move out to process last member from loop. And of course, don't write to file in the loop, move it out. In addition, you can check amount of reacords and if there are huge records to use Parallel For instead during reading

Comment: @EugenePetrov: The condition is there to prevent adding a comma after the last item. Also, the place where he uses `foreach` is unlikely to be his bottleneck. Changing that code would make almost no difference in the run time.

Comment: @JimMischel : He is using the same condition as in the for, there is no prevention here, when he get last element in i_a for check, if i_a <= arr_count(arr_count - the last index element, he must use <) is true it goes into the body, the if does the same. Am I not right? I suggested remove the condition from loop it makes it faster

Comment: *he must use < - I told about if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two primary issues. First, you should open the `StreamReader` at the beginning of the loop, and close it after you're done. Like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sFilename, false, Encoding.UTF8)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // convert here
        // Each line is written to the StreamWriter
    }
}
```

The `using` construct will ensure that the `StreamWriter` is properly closed and disposed.

The second issue is appending things to strings. Rather than appending strings, use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder s_fields = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder s_values = new StringBuilder();
int arr_count = _Arr.Count - 1;
while (_dr.Read()) 
{
    for(int i_a = 0; i_a <= arr_count;i_a++)
    {
        if (i_a <= arr_count)
        {
            s_fields.AppendFormat("{0},", _Arr[i_a].ToString());
            s_values.AppendFormat("'{0}',", _dr[i_a].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            s_fields.Append(_Arr[i_a].ToString());
            s_values.AppendFormat("'{0}'", _dr[i_a].ToString());
        }
    }
    strSQL = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})",
        sTableName, s_fields.ToString(), s_values.ToString());
    sw.WriteLine(strSQL);
}
```

That should improve your performance quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

SqlBulkCopy class helped me once. [Link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think your major culprit is the `new StreamWriter(sFileName, true, Encoding.UTF8)` line of code. For each data row you are opening the file, adding the single command, and then closing the file. That would be very inefficient.

Try using a `StringBuilder` instead of writing to the stream and then, outside of the reading loop, write the string built using the `StringBuilder` to the file just once.

I think you'll find that this speeds things up enormously.

Comment: That'll work as long as the total amount of data he's writing doesn't exceed 1 billion characters.

Comment: @JimMischel - He could then do partial writes then, but I suspect that if that's a limit he's hitting then he might have many more problems. It'd be one very large table.

Comment: A couple of gigabytes doesn't sound like a very large table to me.